# Data transmission in optical fibers

Tags: semiconductor-physics, computational-physics, fiber-optics

Im reading though my Network Architecture lecture notes and it states optical fibers need a repeater every >10km. Repeaters are used to amplify digital signals but the notes do not explain or state what signal type this medium transmits. I would like to know **what signal type do optical fibers carry**

Comment: Light. http://www.thefoa.org/tech/wavelength.htm - There are 'windows' of wavelength than can be exploited. These are around 650 and 850 nanometers for plastic fibers, 850 and 1300 nm for multimodal glass fibers and 1310, 1490-1625 nm for single mode glass fibers.

Comment: Good info. But in data transmission terms I want to know whether the data transmitted is digital or analog.

Comment: Please edit your question to clarify that when you ask "what signal type" you're asking about analog vs digital rather than about what wavelengths of light, what data rates, or what modulation scheme or any of the other distinctions that might be made about signal type.

Comment: the question is clear and Peltio answer accurate

Answer (score 1):

it actually transmits pulses on light through the optical fibers which can be considered as zeros and ones. Like if there is light it is one and otherwise it is zero.
Eventhough you are transmitting the light there are loses due to the quantun short noise and TIR loses. So in order to modify the signal to its orginal state the network uses the optical repeter which uses stimulated emmission of light and regenrates the power to older signals

Answer (score 0):

An optical fiber is neither digital or analog; It's just a conduit for a beam of light.  But, in any kind of long-haul telecommunications application, it most likely will be transmitting a baseband-modulated bit stream (i.e., digital data) at many gigabits per second.

Comment: If the transmission is a beam of light,  **(a) how does attenuation occur in the case of light? **. **(b) in case of the long haul communication system,  why carry the modulated signal as digital and not analog based stream?**

Comment: @GomezganiPhiri, if you want answers to those questions, please ask them as new questions on the site. The first one is okay for physics.SE, but the second would probably fit better on [EE](http://electronics.stackexchange.com).

Comment: At least historically, cable TV distribution often used analog signals in optical fiber. Other than that, telecom and datacom fiber optics have been 100% digital, as far as I know.

Comment: That fiber is "baseband" is not entirely true since wavelength division multiplexing is being used to transmit multiple channels on a single fiber.

Comment: @GomezganiPhiri, it's not just attenuation:  There's also _dispersion_.  Different wavelengths travel at different speeds in the fiber.  As a consequence, when a nice sharp-edged waveform goes into the fiber at one end, the waveform that comes out 10km down the line is not as distinct.  A long-haul optical system may contain analog amplifiers, and it may also contain digital _repeaters_ that re-shape the signal.